# how to get distinct result from the oracle sql query below?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT  FCR.FCR_ID,
        FCR.FCR_TITLE FCR_TITLE,
        to_char(FCR.FCR_DATE_SUB, 'fmDD Mon YYYY') DATEIN 
FROM    PMP_SCRIPT        FCR,
        PMP_SCRIPT_PART CST, 
        PMP_USER              USR,
        PMP_SCRIPT_EVENTS PST
WHERE   CST.CST_ROLE  = 'MANAGER'   and 
        CST.CST_STATUS    = 'ADDED'   and 
        CST.CST_USR_ID    = 1573752923320092       and 
        PST.PST_EVENTTYPE = 'ONREVIEW' and 
        PST.PST_FCR_ID    = CST.CST_FCR_ID     and  
        PST.PST_USR_ID    = USR.USR_ID       and   
        PST.PST_FCR_ID    = FCR.FCR_ID  
ORDER  BY FCR.FCR_DATE_CREATED;
```

I Got the following results

```
        PAGES               TITLE                           DATEIN
        6746061995031488    complex ecosystem               20 Oct 2014
        1057034726101865    mutated seabed cores            20 Feb 2013
        1057034726101865    mutated seabed cores            20 Feb 2013
        2174332191071984    Cheomtherapy Structure design   09 Jan 2013
        6541320181289621    Earthquake  Epicenter           21 Dec 2013
        6541320181289621    Earthquake  Epicenter           21 Dec 2014
        6541320181289621    Earthquake  Epicenter           21 Dec 2013
        6541320181289621    Earthquake  Epicenter           21 Dec 2013
        6541320181289621    Earthquake  Epicenter           21 Dec 2013
        6541320181289621    Earthquake  Epicenter           21 Dec 2013
        6541320181289621    Earthquake  Epicenter           21 Dec 2013
```

**But i want to get all unique results, can someone help me out**
**I already tried this with distinct keyword, but query gave "not selection expression**

Comment: Please post the query that gives error

Comment: How about `select distinct`.  However, I would encourage you to understand why you are getting duplicates and to fix the rest of the query.

Comment: 1. Are you sure, your query returns the right results? Isn't there any error in the query logic (especially `WHERE` clause) causing the query returning dupliate values? 2. You got the `not selection expression` error, because you were sorting the query results by the column not being returned by the query.

Comment: yes logic properly inplemented

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a distinct over inline query. Maybe this will help you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM
  (SELECT FCR.FCR_ID,
    FCR.FCR_TITLE FCR_TITLE,
    TO_CHAR(FCR.FCR_DATE_SUB, 'fmDD Mon YYYY') DATEIN
  FROM PMP_SCRIPT FCR,
    PMP_SCRIPT_PART CST,
    PMP_USER USR,
    PMP_SCRIPT_EVENTS PST
  WHERE CST.CST_ROLE    = 'MANAGER'
  AND CST.CST_STATUS    = 'ADDED'
  AND CST.CST_USR_ID    = 1573752923320092
  AND PST.PST_EVENTTYPE = 'ONREVIEW'
  AND PST.PST_FCR_ID    = CST.CST_FCR_ID
  AND PST.PST_USR_ID    = USR.USR_ID
  AND PST.PST_FCR_ID    = FCR.FCR_ID
  ORDER BY FCR.FCR_DATE_CREATED
  )A ;
```

Comment: So basically what we have done, we have converted your query into a inline query and aliased it as 'A'. Now we are doing a DISTINCT on that inline view to get desired output.

Comment: If it helped can u plz accept the answer so that ot can be useful for other readers